# Emacs: Performance of keybinding to an anonymous function

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

My two options are

**Define the function before binding**

For example:

```
(defun select-all ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-whole-buffer))
```

Then binding it:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'select-all)
```

**Bind anonymous function**

Define and bind in one go:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
          (mark-whole-buffer)))
```

**My Question**

If I define and bind in one go, is there any performance implication?

**References**

[emacswiki.org - InteractiveKeybinding](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveKeybinding) seems to inform us that it is acceptable.

Comment: It is `global-set-key`, *not* `global-key-set`.  There is no difference in performance.  If it is for yourself and you don't care about `C-h k` looking up a key binding and jumping to the source code, then do it either way.  If you someday wish to create a library that others will use, then you definitely want the first approach.  If you look at some of the popular libraries, you'll see that no one uses the second approach.  Try looking up the keybinding yourself with `C-h k` and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: I think it's worth it to give the function a name just so `C-h k` gives you something useful.  If it's important enough to give a keybind, it's probably important enough to name.

Comment: BTW, `mark-whole-buffer` is already interactive, so there's no reason to define a wrapper function.  You can do `(defalias 'select-all 'mark-whole-buffer)` to give it an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance hit with respect to general use of the binding. There may be a small performance hit with respect to other commands which use that information, such as C-h k, but that is also so small it is unlikely you will even notice it and given you probably don't use C-h k that frequently, the most inefficient component in the equation is the user.

There are two main benefits with defining a funtion and then binding that rather than just doing a lambda

1. Reuse. Having a named function means you can use it with M-x or potentially use it in other functions or libraries you write.
2. Documentation. This is an important one. I have often found myself looking at a lambda based key binding and having to work through it to remember exactly what it does. If on the other hand it had been a named function I was binding to, then it would likely have been more obvious. You also get the C-h k stuff and apropos support for a named function.

I therefore tend ot only use the lambda type binding when it is really trivial and obvious what it is doing and use a named funtion for all other times.

Comment: Two more: (1) Easy to advise. (2) Easy to add and (especially) remove from hooks.